# Neo4j self-relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

What's the proper way to create a relation from an instance of a Neo4j class to another instance of that class?

For example, if I am modeling courses in a course catalog with a model for courses that are prereqs for other courses.

I am using neo4j with rails:

Model:

> class Course < Neo4j::Rails::Model   property :name
>   has_n(:prereqs).from(Course, :leadstos)   has_n(:leadstos)

Creating objects and relation:

```
algebra = Course.create :name => 'algebra'
arithmetic = Course.create :name => 'arithmetic'
algebra.prereqs << arithmetic 
algebra.save!
arithmetic.save!

algebra.prereqs.each {|node| puts node [:name]}

#prints 'arithmetic'
```

However, `arithmetic.leadstos.each {|node| puts node[:name]}` comes out as blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to declare :leadtos relation as

```
has_n(:leadstos).to(Course)
```